# Мозкобіль чи мізкобіль?

Tags: неологізми

Якби таке слово існувало в українській мові, то по правилам воно було би "мізкобіль" чи "мозкобіль"?

З одного боку, є "мозкові" сорти гороху.
З іншого боку, є "мізкувати".

Comment: На жаль, відповіді на такі запитання можуть бути лише суб'єктивними, а отже запитання має бути закритим як Opinion-based. Ви можете врятувати запитання, якщо зосередитесь на тонкощах сенсів, які ви хочете передати цим неологізмом.

Comment: @bytebuster хіба немає правил словотвору? Чому лиш суб'єктивні відповіді?

Comment: Я згоден з P. Vovk. (Хоча все тією чи іншою мірою має багато винятків і, відповідно, елемент суб'єктивності неминучий, але не думаю, що ця царина суб'єктивніша за інші.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Деякі старі словники подають «мізковий»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

- Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898 (М. Уманець, А. Спілка):

  > Мозгово́й = мізкови́й.
- Російсько-український словник 1930 (О. Ізюмов):

  > Мозговой – мізкови́й, -а́, -е́.
- або обидва варіанти.

У старій літературі ми теж іноді бачимо «мізковий» або обидва варіанти в одного автора:

- Іван Франко:

  > Правда, доктор висловляв ясно і докладно богато таких думок, до яких і вона сама дійшла дорогою досьвіду і власної мізкової працї, але чому-ж то ті думки, висловлювані його устами, були в її очах такі нові, принадні й цїнні, вилїтали перед її розумовим зором мов яркі, огнисті ракети? («Маніпулянтка», 1888, [1906](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%97%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%96_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%97%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0))

  > Значить, або маємо діло з якоюсь хоробою тісно психічною, що має своє гніздо в якімсь незначущім мізковім центрі і не має впливу на звичайні органічні функції — адже медицина знає такі хороби! — або, може… («Для домашнього огнища», 1892)

  Слід зазначити, що Франко все-таки частіше писав «мозковий» (приклади не навожу).
- Гнат Хоткевич:

  > А сама вона, Велика наука, той стовп серединний знання, що заклався навіки кріпко з мізкових кліток міліярдів будівничих — вона ніколи не говорила так («Біла (флюїда)», 1902).
- Михайло Яцків:

  > Патлатий вичерпався фізично в дуже короткім часі, занепав на мізкову хворобу і рятував останки сил утечею від Ольги («Блискавиці», 1913).

Також, хоч я в цьому не спеціаліст, але мені про природність варіанта *мізковий* каже походження слова — від праслов'янського «*mozgъ». Адже зазвичай схема така: праслов'янське «o» переходить в українське «і» («*konь» → «кінь», «*kotъ» → «кіт», «*nosъ» → «ніс»), а праслов'янське «ъ» — в українське «о» («*sъnъ» → «сон», «*rъtъ» → «рот», «*lъbъ» → «лоб») — хоча є, звісно, багато винятків. (Цікава також доля іншого винятку: раніше принаймні іноді (я припускаю, на заході України) в значенні «божество» вживали [«біг» («Біг»)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=65307&page=40) — це теж коректніше етимологічно («*bogъ») — але зрештою інші діалекти (я припускаю, східніші) перемогли (а «біг» як «бігати» у деяких варіантах правопису було «бїг»).)

Тобто ми мали б мати не лише «мізкобіль», а й, можливо, «мізковий» (і навіть «Біг»).

Comment: дуже дякую! Щодо Біг -- в творах вживається слово "бігме", яке ймовірне має саме таку природу словотвору.

Comment: @danbst, саме так!